# Task always pass a past value to a function in a iteration

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am creating a service in dynamics 365 crm plugin which is based on C#.
There is a class service containing a function which creates a task for each data in list to submit the data to separate function. However for each iteration of data list, the function always submit the first data in a list.

```
public void SubmitPubconDataByCreatingTask(HeadersAndData headersAndData, PubconMessage message)
{
    string mainLabel = "exampleLabel";
    PubconService pubconService = new PubconService(appSetting.PunconUrl, tracingService);
    List<Task> submissionTaks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (List<object> item in headersAndData.data[exampleLabel])
    {
        PubconBody newPubconBody = new PubconBody();
        HeadersAndData newHeadersAndData = headersAndData;
        List<List<object>> newSingleList = new List<List<object>>();

        newSingleList.Add(item);
        newHeadersAndData.data[mainQueryLabel] = newSingleList;
        message.AddHeadersAndData = newHeadersAndData;
        newPubconBody.AddMessage(message);

        Task task = Task.Run(() => pubconService.SubmitData(newPubconBody));
        submissionTaks.Add(task);
     }

     Task.WaitAll(submissionTaks.ToArray());
}
```

Here, message contains a list of data, where I am trying to replace a list with a single data for each iteration.

Comment: `PubconService` - typically client proxies (regardless of tech) are not suitable for _concurrent calls_ by multiple threads and/or tasks.  Either make your code single-threaded or create a new `PubconService` proxy per call.

Comment: The pubcon service is being created for each iteration. But it is not solving the problem.

Comment: Do these threads use a single `IOrganizationService` instance? If that's the case either access to this instance should be synchronized or every thread should be assigned its own instance.